# Sorting a generic collection

Tags: java, generics, sorting, collections

I searched but couldn't find any answer on how to sort my own generic collection class.

I have these four classes:

**2nd edit**
Simplified code, applied Evgeniy's suggestion but still doesn't sort, wired :\

A Track class:

```
public class Track {
    private Integer id;
    private String interpreter;
    private String title;
    Track(int id,String interpreter,String title) {
        this.id=id;
        this.interpreter=interpreter;
        this.title=title;
    }
    public String getInterpreter() {
        return this.interpreter;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public String getCompleteName() {
        return this.id+"\t"+this.interpreter.toString()+" - "+this.title.toString();
    }
}
```

A TrackContainer class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TrackContainer<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    ArrayList<T> arraylist;

    TrackContainer() {
        arraylist = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public boolean insertTrack(T track) {
        if(arraylist.add(track)) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void listAllTracks(java.util.Iterator<T> iterat) {
        while(iterat.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterat.next());
        }
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arraylist.iterator();
    }
}
```

A TrackIDComparator class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
public class TrackIDComparator implements Comparator<Track> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Track t1, Track t2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Comparable id1 = (Comparable)(t1.getID());
        Comparable id2 = (Comparable)(t2.getID());
        return id1.compareTo(id2);
    }
}
```

And finally a Main class:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrackContainer<Track> ltc = new TrackContainer<Track>();
        ltc.insertTrack(new Track(2,"trackname1","tracktitle1"));
        ltc.insertTrack(new Track(1,"trackname2","tracktitle2"));
        ltc.insertTrack(new Track(3,"trackname3","tracktitle3"));

        System.out.println("unsorted:");
        Iterator<Track> it = ltc.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next().getCompleteName());
        }

        System.out.println("sorted:");
        Collections.sort(ltc,new TrackIDComparator());
        Iterator<Track> it2 = ltc.iterator();
        while(it2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it2.next().getCompleteName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
unsorted:
2   trackname1 - tracktitle1
1   trackname2 - tracktitle2
3   trackname3 - tracktitle3
sorted:
2   trackname1 - tracktitle1
1   trackname2 - tracktitle2
3   trackname3 - tracktitle3
```

Comment: `sort` expects a `List` or a subclass of `List` as its first argument, which your custom list is not.

Comment: Where's TrackContainer?  You've only shown us ListTrackContainer.

Comment: Bascially it means you need `TrackContainer` to implement the `List` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way is to change TrackContainer

`public class TrackContainer<T> extends ArrayList<Track<T>>`

Remove the `arraylist` member variable and use `this` in any overriden methods.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself, but you forgot mentioning how to actually sort the TrackContainer afterwards (by using Collections.sort method).

Comment: Simon, I indeed have still problems applying U Mad's suggestion

Comment: How does Collections.sort(...) in Main class looks like? I also have no overridden methods in TrackContainer

Comment: `Collections.sort(ltc,new TrackIDComparator());` should work fine, provided the comparator is correctly written.
You can use pastebin.com to show the code.

Comment: `Collections.sort(ltc,new TrackIDComparator<String>());` seems to be correct, but it doesn't sort.

Comment: It sorts by hashcode of ID. I'm not sure that's what you want, because hashcodes are pretty random, so your comparator sorts into a random order. If you want to sort properly by ID, you need to change the comparator function to:
`return ((Comparable<T>)o1.getID()).compareTo(o2);`
Obvious caveat is that if you are using strings for your IDs, `"10"` is less than `"2"`.

Comment: I simplified the code but it unfortunately still doesn't sort

Comment: You ignored what I said about not using an arrayList member. You extend arrayList and also contain one. We're getting nowhere so I just coded it for you: http://pastebin.com/mTKAT2t0
Just use this.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Thanks. Is it still possible to have this in the Main `TrackContainer<Track<Integer>> tc` instead of `TrackContainer<Integer> tc` ?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but I'm not sure what's the point then, since `TrackContainer<Track<Integer>>` is pretty much the same as `List<Track<Integer>>`

Answer (score 3):

Just add sort() method to TrackContainer

```
public void sort()  {
    Collections.sort(arraylist, new TrackIDComparator()); 
}
```

UPDATE

It's not clear why Track is generic and why T id; T interpreter; T title; should have the same type. I suggest to revise the design. Anyway,

```
class TrackIDComparator 

     public int compare(Track<T> o1, Track<T> o2) {
           if(o1.getID().hashCode() > o2.getID().hashCode())
               return 1;
...
```

is incorrect, change it as

```
public int compare(Track<T> o1, Track<T> o2) {
      Comparable id1 = (Comparable)(o1.getId());
      Comparable id2 = (Comparable)(o2.getId());
      return id1.compareTo(id2);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with U Mad's answer (it compiles now, but doesn't sort, wired)

Comment: See my update, should help, but something is general design I guess

Comment: There's this error with your `The method getId() is undefined for the type Comparable` (changed to getID()) I can't solve it :\

Comment: rigth, my bad, will fix now, still the idea is the same

Comment: I simplified the classes and applied your suggestion but it still doesn't sort :\

Answer (score 1):

`TrackContainer<T>` is not a `List` - if you want to use [`Collections.sort(List,Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) on it, you should make it `implements List<T>` (and implement all interface methods, of course).

Comment: I would suggest implementing a sort method inside the TrackContainer which uses Collections.sort on the internal list (if no need to support Collections.sort)

Comment: amit, implementing all the List methods sounds like a lot of work. Aviram, Evgeniy's suggestion works. Still trying to use Collections.sort within the Main class.

Answer (score 0):

`TrackContainer` isn't a `List`, so you cannot use `Collections.sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T> c)` method.

Alternatively, you want to sort `TrackContainer.arrayList` field, so I would suggest to add a sort method that accepts a `Comparator<Track<T>>` to do the sorting internally.

Also, you would want to do `new TrackIDComparator<String>()` when binding `Track` to a type.